# Pandas Coalesce Multiple Columns, NaN

Tags: python, pandas, coalesce

I want to `coalesce` 4 columns using pandas. I've tried this:

`final['join_key'] = final['book'].astype('str') + final['bdr'] + final['cusip'].fillna(final['isin']).fillna(final['Deal'].astype('str')).fillna(final['Id'])`

When I use this it returns:

```
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+------------+------------------+
| book  |  bdr   | cusip | isin | Deal |     Id     |     join_key     |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+------------+------------------+
| 17236 | ETFROS |       |      |      | 8012398421 | 17236.0ETFROSnan |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+------------+------------------+
```

The field `Id` is not properly appending to my `join_key` field.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Update**:

```
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+
|  endOfDay  | book | bdr  |   cusip   |     isin     | Deal |     Id     |          join_key          |
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR | 371494AM7 | US371494AM77 |  161 | 8013210731 | 20191031|15|ITOR|371494AM7 |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011898573 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011898742 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011899418 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+

df['join_key'] = ("20191031|" + df['book'].astype('str') + "|" + df['bdr'] + "|" + df[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'id']].bfill(1)['cusip'].astype(str))
```

For some reason this code isnt picking up `Id` as part of the key.

Comment: Please add the input

Comment: Isnt the table i showed the input? What do you mean?

Comment: Is that the input or the output? You wrote "When I use this it returns" ... so I tought this was the output.

Comment: try to remove the `astype(str)` after `final['Deal']` and put it outside of all `fillna` like: `final['cusip'].fillna(final['isin']).fillna(final['Deal']).fillna(final['Id']).astype('str')`

Comment: @Ben.T hey ben, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last chain `fillna` for `cusip` is too complicated. You may change it to `bfill`

```
final['join_key'] = (final['book'].astype('str') + 
                     final['bdr'] + 
                     final[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'Id']].bfill(1)['cusip'].astype(str))
```

Comment: thanks andy, seems to work, however my `book` value keeps returning a `.` after the string

Comment: it is a `float64`

Comment: I get the following error, `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: it means some rows of column `book` has `NaN` or `None` values. You need to decide on how to handle those `NaN`. For example: assign `0` to those `NaN` as follows: `final['book'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: Is it possible to leave those blanks?

Comment: Yes, but don't fillna with blank because blank will cause error to to `astype(int)`. Instead, do the final step replace as: `final['book'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).replace('0', '')`

Comment: Hi Andy, 2 questions, why do you use `cusip` twice? Also I am having trouble appending my last column `Id` to this? It seems to append up to `Deal`

Comment: `final[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'Id']]` slices 4 columns from `final`. It returns new df with 4 columns and doing `bfill` on this 4-columns df. After tha ,from this 4-columns df, chain the second `['cusip']` to get only the column `cusip` which was already filled by `bfill`. Could you post rows which has issue with appending?

Comment: in the last 3 rows, values of `'cusip', 'isin', 'Deal'` are empty strings or blank  spaces, so `bfill` doesn't fill anything. `final[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'Id']].bfill(1)['cusip'].astype(str))` equivalents to the original `final['cusip`] which has values `[371494AM7, '', '', '']`. Therefore, it doesn't pick `Id`

Comment: ah I see, so how can I get it to pick the correct value?  Seems like something like this was working, but not till `Id` : `final['cusip'].fillna(final['isin']).fillna(final['Deal']).fillna(final['Id']).astype('str')`

Comment: `fillna` is the same as `bfill`. They require `NaN` to fill. You need to replace those blank/empty spaces with `NaN` before using `bfill` or `fillna`. However, your original question and sample indicated your data having `NaN`, not empty space. To avoid confusion and having more space to discuss, could you split this issue to a new question? The comment section doesn't have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup (ignore)   
final = pd.DataFrame({
    'book': [17236],
    'bdr': ['ETFROS'],
    'cusip': [np.nan],
    'isin': [np.nan],
    'Deal': [np.nan],
    'Id': ['8012398421'],
})

# answer
final['join_key'] = final['book'].astype('str') + final['bdr'] + final['cusip'].fillna(final['isin']).fillna(final['Deal']).fillna(final['Id']).astype('str')
```

Output

```
    book    bdr     cusip   isin    Deal    Id          join_key
0   17236   ETFROS  NaN     NaN     NaN     8012398421  17236ETFROS8012398421
```